# After upload a media file can not play the file in angular 2, shows 404 not found

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a problem in Angular2: I have module for media upload (Images/Videos). So upload module is working perfect but after uploading the file when I try to watch the video or view the image file, I get a 404 Not Found error. But if i run ng build and refresh it again I can watch the video or view the image files. Am i doing something wrong or we can handle this with someway?

GET http://localhost:4200/dist/assets/mediauploads/Desktop%20(19).jpg 404 (Not Found)

```
//This is my node js code

socket.on('Upload', function (data){
    var Name = data['Name'];
    Files[Name]['Downloaded'] += data['Data'].length;
    Files[Name]['Data'] += data['Data'];
    if(Files[Name]['Downloaded'] == Files[Name]['FileSize']) //If File is Fully Uploaded
    {
        fs.write(Files[Name]['Handler'], Files[Name]['Data'], null, 'Binary', function(err, Writen){
           var inp = fs.createReadStream("./src/assets/temp/" + Name);
           var out = fs.createWriteStream("./src/assets/mediauploads/" + Name);

          inp.pipe(out);
                  inp.on("end", function() {
                      var path="./src/assets/temp/" + Name;
                      var tempFile = fs.openSync(path, 'r');
                      if(fs.existsSync(path)){
                      fs.closeSync(tempFile);
                       fs.unlinkSync(path);
                       socket.emit('Done', {'Image' : './src/assets/mediauploads/' + Name});
                      }

                  });
        });
    }
    else if(Files[Name]['Data'].length > 10485760){ //If the Data Buffer reaches 10MB
        fs.write(Files[Name]['Handler'], Files[Name]['Data'], null, 'Binary', function(err, Writen){
            Files[Name]['Data'] = ""; //Reset The Buffer
            var Place = Files[Name]['Downloaded'] / 524288;
            var Percent = (Files[Name]['Downloaded'] / Files[Name]['FileSize']) * 100;
            socket.emit('MoreData', { 'Place' : Place, 'Percent' :  Percent});
        });
    }
    else
    {
        var Place = Files[Name]['Downloaded'] / 524288;
        var Percent = (Files[Name]['Downloaded'] / Files[Name]['FileSize']) * 100;
        socket.emit('MoreData', { 'Place' : Place, 'Percent' :  Percent});
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you post the code for your upload module?

Comment: So, from what I see of your code, `.` refers to the directory from where you are running your server script. Your server script seems to be outside both your `dist` and `src` folder and  you are serving file from `dist` but uploading them to `src`. For now just changing the upload folder to `dist` should be enough. Eventually you'll need to develop a solution so that your server and the SPA it's serving are linked in a more explicit way (right now they are only linked by their relative location in the filesystem). For example you could add a property for the spa root folder.

Comment: Another thing I just noted, you are allowing the client to decide the file name and even the location of your file. This has security problems. Think what would happen if the client sent you a file `../../index.html`

Comment: Thnx @jspurim ! After production src folder will be there or not? so that i can change the upload path  to `dist` folder

Comment: i'm validation the file format and other required validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `ng build` the angular app is built into the `dist` folder. My guess is you have your app setup in such a way you are actually uploading the image into your `src/assets` folder. 
As you are running the app from the `dist` folder your newly uploaded image/video is not visible. When you rebuild the app the file is copied to the `dist` folder and becomes accesible.

Comment: you're right jspurim. I'm uploading files in src/assets/uploads/ directory and from node js i'm using this code

Comment: app.use('/', express.static('dist'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

Comment: Glad it helped you. One more thing. Keep in mind the `dist` folder is the app you would deploy to your server. That is, in a production environment, the src folder may not even exist, your code should not reference it. You should make sure you upload your files in a path **relative** to where your app is deployed.

Comment: Another thing, when you post code, use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format it.

Comment: would you please give me some code snippet so that i'll me more clear about this. And thnx for being helpful

Comment: The specifics of the code depend on exaclty what you are doing. If you post the code for your upload module I may be able to help you modify it.

Comment: `socket.on('Upload', function (data){
        var Name = data['Name'];
        Files[Name]['Downloaded'] += data['Data'].length;
        Files[Name]['Data'] += data['Data'];
        if(Files[Name]['Downloaded'] == Files[Name]['FileSize']) //If File is Fully Uploaded
        {
            fs.write(Files[Name]['Handler'], Files[Name]['Data'], null, 'Binary', function(err, Writen){
               var inp = fs.createReadStream("./src/assets/temp/" + Name);
               var out = fs.createWriteStream("./src/assets/mediauploads/" + Name);`

Comment: `//Upload File function
uploadVideo(){
  var filename=this.SelectedFile.name;
  var filesrc="../../assets/mediauploads/"+filename;
  var data={
      filename: filename,
      filesrc: filesrc
    }
    this.mediaService.saveMedia(data).subscribe(response=>{
      console.log(response);
    }, (err)=>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  this.StartUpload();
    
  }`

Comment: Please just edit your answer and add the code there with proper indenting, it's hard to read it this way.

Comment: @jspurim can you help me in that. I am also getting 404 error when trying to show image without build. So how to fix this?

Comment: @NewUser you should probably ask a new question and provide details about your specific problem. This question is already answered.

Comment: @jspurim here I have asked the question please have a look into it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105270/angular-shows-404-not-found-in-the-frontend-when-image-has-been-uploaded-but-sho

Comment: @RajatGupta can you answer my question. I am struggling with the issue just like yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105270/angular-shows-404-not-found-in-the-frontend-when-image-has-been-uploaded-but-sho