# Angular shows 404 not found in the frontend when image has been uploaded but shows image if angular build has done

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

I am using angular 5 with Node js, express and mongodb to upload images with some data. All the data are saving into mongodb without any issue but when I am trying to show the uploaded images it is showing 404 not found even the image is still exist in the uploads folder. I have even tried to hardcode the path with the image name but still its showing 404 error. But if I make some change in the angular code(which builts angular after some chnages) or built the angular it shows the image.

I searched on stackoverflow and got similar issue  like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738262/after-upload-a-media-file-can-not-play-the-file-in-angular-2-shows-404-not-foun/44738576?noredirect=1#comment85039207_44738576) so now I am uploading images in the nodejs root folder.

Here is the code for express.js

```
/* ===================
Import Node Modules
=================== */
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const appRoot = require('app-root-path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

const multer = require('multer');
//custom module

const event = require('../config/routes/event.router');

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // Allows heroku to set port
 mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
//assigning value 
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'devlopment';
/**
 * Assiging port to server
 */
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port + ' in ' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ' mode');
});

/**
 * Database connection
 */
mongoose.connect(config.uri, {
  //useMongoClient: true,
}, (err) => {
  // Check if database was able to connect
  if (err) {
    console.log('Could NOT connect to database: ', err); // Return error message
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to ' + config.db); // Return success message
  }
});

/** 
 * Require Middleware
*/
app.use(helmet());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
/**
 * Every Http request start from index file
 */
app.use(express.static(path.join(appRoot.path, 'dist')));

app.use('/api/event', event); //Event Router

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(appRoot.path, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

Here is my event.router.js file looks like this

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Event = require('../../model/event.model');

var multer  = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/uploads/');
  },

  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    let ext = file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.'), file.originalname.length);
    cb(null, Date.now() + ext);
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('eventimage');


/* SAVE EVENT */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next)  {
  upload(req, res, function(err) {
    if( req.body.eventname == undefined || req.body.eventname == '' ) {
      res.json({ success : false, message: 'You must provide event name!' });
    }
    else if( req.file == undefined || req.file == '' ) {
      res.json({ success : false, message: 'You must provide event image!' });
    }
    else {
      let event =  new Event ({
          _id             : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
          eventname       : req.body.eventname,
          eventimage      : req.file,        
      });
      event.save((err) => {
        if(err) {
          if( err.errors ) {
            if( err.errors.eventname ) {
              res.json({ success: false, message: err.errors.eventname.message });
            }
          }
          else {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Could not save Event. Error: ', err });
          }
        }
        else {
          res.json({ success: true, message: 'Event saved'});
        }

      });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my event-create.component.html looks like

```
<div class="container col-md-12">
  <h1 class="page-header">Create Event</h1>

  <form [formGroup] = "form" (ngSubmit)="onEventSubmit()">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="eventname">Event Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Event Name" formControlName="eventname">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="eventimage">Upload Image For Event</label>
        <image-upload name="eventimage"  [max]="1" [buttonCaption]="'Select Event Image!'"
  [extensions]="['jpg','png']" (removed)="onRemoved($event)"
  (uploadFinished)="onUploadFinished($event)"
  (uploadStateChanged)="onUploadStateChanged($event)" [class]="'eventimage'">
        </image-upload>
      </div>
      <input  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

event-create.component.ts looks like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormControlName } from '@angular/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name';
import { FileHolder } from "angular2-image-upload/lib/image-upload/image-upload.component";
import { EventService } from '../event.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-create',
  templateUrl: './event-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-create.component.css']
})


export class EventCreateComponent implements OnInit {
  public file_form;
  public eventData;
  form :  FormGroup;
  formData = new FormData();

  constructor(
    private formBuilder : FormBuilder,
    private eventService : EventService
    ) { this.createEventForm() }

  createEventForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      eventname: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(5)
      ])],
      eventimage: ['',]
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      eventname: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]),
      eventimage: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

  onEventSubmit() {
    if( this.file_form == undefined ) {
      let formData:FormData = new FormData();
      this.file_form = formData;
    }
    this.eventData = this.file_form;


    this.eventData.append('eventname', this.form.value.eventname);


    this.eventService.addNewEvent(this.eventData).subscribe( data => {
        if( !data.success ) {
          this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger';
          this.message = data.message;
        }
        else {
          this.messageClass = 'alert alert-success';
          this.message = data.message;
        }
      });
  }

  public onUploadFinished(file: FileHolder) {
    this.formData.append('eventimage', file.file, file.file.name);
    this.file_form = this.formData;
  }

}
```

Here is the event details where I am getting the data from mongodb with image

event-detail.component.ts looks like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params} from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { EventService } from '../../../admin/events/event.service';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-detail',
  templateUrl: './event-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-detail.component.css'],
})
export class EventDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  event = {};
  eventname;
  absolutePath = 'public/uploads';


  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    protected eventService: EventService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.switchMap((params: Params) => {
    let id = params['id'];
    return this.eventService.getEvent(id);
    }).subscribe(response => {
      this.event = response;
      this.eventname = this.event['eventname'];
      this.eventImage = this.event['eventimage']['filename'];
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });  
  }

}
```

and event-details.component.html looks like this

```
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <img class="event_listing" src= "{absolutePath}/{eventImage}">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h4 class="page-header">{{eventname}}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because we are using dist folder as a static folder.

`app.use(express.static(path.join(appRoot.path, 'dist')));`

what I did is, I build the whole application using the process that you are doing and once we host the website on the server no need to re-build again. Just make sure that you're upload functionality is working properly.

Comment: So shouldn't I use `app.use(express.static(path.join(appRoot.path, 'dist')));`